# Visual Studio Profiling .psess does not exist or is invalid

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiling

I've followed the tutorial to perform project profiling as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372(v=vs.120).aspx).
It worked just fine for a while, but when I try profiling again, I now always get the following error:

[image]

I couldn't find much help online - can anyone help?

**NOTE:** I have a Winforms project with .Net 4.5.2 using the x86 Release build platform.

**Update:** I did re-install VS and re-create my project. It then worked just fine for a while, and reappeared... Anyone has some idea??

Comment: Look already opened sessions on: View->Other Windows->Performance Explorer and delete session with this name. Maybe something wrong with path.

Comment: The Performance Explorer is empty...

Comment: You run always VS as administrator?

Comment: Yes I do run as administrator. And I can see the file is being created. Would posting the file *.press be of any help?
NOTE: I did this on a new project and it doesn't work. After the first "invalid" message I get an error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"... Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it appears that indeed, it is related to extensions. More specifically, in my case, it turned out that the bug was related to the Automatic Versions extension.

Take a look at `Tool -> Extensions and Updates` and try updating what shows under "Updates"...

Once I did updates and repairs of those, it started working fine. Repairing VS itself did, however, not help.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the VS extension "StopOnFirstBuild". Worked for me